# Recursive Text Substitution and File Extension Rename

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using an application that creates a text file on a Linux server. I then have the ability to execute a shell script (BASH 3.2.57) in which I need to convert the text file from Unix line endings to DOS and also change the extension of the file from .txt to .log.

I currently have a sed based command to do this. This command is rewritten by the application at run time to point to the specific folder and file name, in this example where you see ABC (all capital 3 letters in all my examples are a variable that can be any 3 letters).

```
pushd /rootfolder/parentfolder/ABC/
sed 's/$/\r/' prABC.txt > prABC.log
popd
```

The problem with this is that if a user runs the application for 2 different groups, say ABC and DEF at nearly the same time, the script will get overwritten with the DEF variables before ABC had a chance to fire off and do its thing with the file. Additionally the .txt is left in the folder regardless and I would like that to be removed.

A friend of mine came up with the following code that seems to work if its determined to be our best solution, but I would think and hope we have a cleaner more dynamic way to do this. Also this current method requires that when my user decides to add a GHI directory and file I now have to update the code, which i can program my application to do for me but i don't want this script to have to be rewritten every time the application wants to use it.

```
pushd /rootfolder/parentfolder/ABC
if [[ -f prABC.txt ]]
  then
    sed 's/$/\r/' prABC.txt > prABC.log
    rm prABC.txt
fi
popd

pushd /rootfolder/parentfolder/DEF
if [[ -f prABC.txt ]]
  then
    sed 's/$/\r/' prABC.txt > prABC.log
    rm prABC.txt
fi
popd
```

I would like to call this script at anytime from my application and it find any file named pr*.txt below the /rootfolder/parentfolder/ directory (if that has to include the parentfolder in its search that won't be a problem) and convert the line endings from LF to CRLF and change the extension of the file from .txt to .log.

I've done a ton of searching and have found near solutions for this but not exactly what I need and I want to be sure it's as safe as possible (issues with using "find with for". I don't know what utilities are installed on this build so i would like to keep it as basic/supportable as possible Thanks in advance :)

Comment: #1, **don't use the same auto-generated script name** for different "groups". It's easy to generate unique filenames with `mktemp`. `man` it. #2, `find` can locate your files for you. #3, do `sed -i ... && mv <file>.txt <file>.log` rather than trying to do it all with sed (and rm).

Comment: Check `unix2dos` and `dos2unix`, they work great for line endings.  But they are not part of the basic packages...  Your call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should almost never need `pushd` and `popd` in scripts. In fact, you rarely need `cd`, either.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for d in /rootfolder/parentfolder/ABC /rootfolder/parentfolder/DEF
do
  if [[ -f "$d/prABC.txt" ]]
  then
    sed 's/$/\r/' "$d/prABC.txt" > "$d/prABC.log" &&
    rm "$d/prABC.txt"
  fi
done
```

Recall that `a && b` is shorthand for

```
if a; then
    b
fi
```

In other words, if `sed` fails (because the source file can't be read, or the destination can't be written) we don't `rm` the source file. There should be an error message already so we don't add another one.

Not only is this more succinct, it is also easier to change if you decide that the old file should be renamed instead of removed, or you want to filter out all lines which contain "beef" in the `sed` script. Generally you should avoid repeated code; see also [*the DRY principle* on Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Something is seriously wrong somewhere if you require DOS line endings in your files on Unix.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee for reviewing the code. If I am reading your update correctly then I would have to list every subdirectory after the in statement still, right? This current setup has 67 subdirectories. Would I be able to just say

"for d in /rootfolder/parentfolder
do"

for it to check each subfolder below that point?

Something is wrong for sure lol. I'm sending this file to another system that is windows based and their import application is choking on the lack of a CRLF

Comment: `for d in /rootfolder/parentfolder/*/.` will loop through all the subdirectories of `/rootfolder/parentfolder` if that's what you want. If that's not what you want, (accept this answer and) ask a new question with a proper explanation.

Comment: That sir is indeed what I want. Appreciate ya!